# Google Analytics - API calls and dashboard request token consumption

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Are the tokens consumed by API calls and the dashboard request part of the same daily quota?

Comment: What do you mean by api calls to the dashboard?

Comment: Not to the dashboard , both are separate

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you mean by the dashboard i dont understand the question.

Comment: google analytics dashboard

Comment: Assuming you mean the Google analytics website.   Yes you are logged in and it uses an API in the backend.  Your app calling the API is different

Comment: Core Reporting API or the google analytics Web UI does not consume any tokens . The tokens are consumed only if Un-sampled reports are created using the Management API or Web UI

Answer (score 0):

Core Reporting API or the google analytics Web UI does not consume any tokens . 
The tokens are consumed only if Un-sampled reports are created using the Management API or Web UI.